# Don't occasionally/don't sometimes

Tags: adverbs, negation

What are other adverbs that can't be negated just like "sometimes" and "occasionally"?

1. I don't sometimes  drink milk.
2. I don't occasionally drink milk.

Comment: You could try looking up synonyms for _occasionally_!

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Yes, but there would be no information about whether or not they can't be negated.

Comment: Minor point: in fact both of those examples could be valid. Imagine the scenario where saying that someone sometimes or occasionally drinks milk was seen as some kind of insult. The person could reply, in indignation, "How dare you! I don't *sometimes* (or *occasionally*) drink milk! I drink milk pretty much every waking hour!" That's a peculiar case though, and doesn't affect the gist of your question. (Which is why I said it was a minor point.)

Comment: In *most* contexts (as I'm sure OP knows), adverbial ***sometimes, occasionally*** would come *before* negating auxiliary ***don't***. The difference in meaning is easier to see with, say, ***often***. Thus (1) *I **often don't** feel hungry* = "There are many occasions when don't feel hungry" (it's relatively common for me not to feel hungry), as opposed to (2) *I **don't often** feel hungry* (making the point that it's relatively rare for me to feel hungry).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, but do *sometimes* and *occasionally* in this position:  I sometimes don't and I occasionally don't mean "there are many occasions when I don't feel hungry?" Or do they  mean in this position that "it's relatively rare for me to feel hungry?" Because with "often" it's easy to see how the meaning changes as you showed. I could also use "sometimes" at the beginning and the end of my sentence. A "I don't drink milk sometimes" and B "sometimes I don't drink milk". Will sentences A and B including "I don't sometimes drink milk" have both meanings below?

Comment: @FumbleFingers 1. There are many occasions when I don't drink milk" and 2. It's rare for me to drink it."

Comment: It's perfectly idiomatic to put ***often*** before OR after negating ***don't*** as in my examples, and I assume you can understand how that changes the meaning. It's NOT normally idiomatic to put ***sometimes, occasionally*** before ***don't*** as in the examples in your question text. The only context I can think of where doing this would be acceptable is if someone just said ***You sometimes /  occasionally drink milk*** and you were ***emphatically refuting*** that assertion (with the meaning *No, you're mistaken. I **never** drink milk!*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No adverbs of frequency can be negated the way you suggest. This is because an adverb of frequency defines how often you *do* something. When you define how often you *don't* do something, you are actually defining a break in a routine, and we would instead refer to the break as something we *do* rather than something we don't.

For example, "I sometimes drink milk" means you only drink milk *occasionally*. The opposite to that would be to say "I drink milk *often*".

However, if you said that you *always* drank milk - perhaps suggesting that it is your drink of choice, or that you drink it every day - you could make an exception to this by saying "*sometimes I don't drink milk*", which would mean that there are occasions when you drink something else. It works with 'occasionally', too, and likely most adverbs of frequency could be used in this negative way.

Comment: is this the only position of "sometimes" that can have this meaning?  I mean this one "sometimes I don't drink milk", which would mean that there are occasions when you drink something else." Can "I don't drink milk sometimes" and "I sometimes don't drink milk" have this meaning too?

Comment: It doesn't usually make sense to say *I sometimes don't [verb]* or *Sometimes I don't [verb]* unless *[to verb]* is something you would *normally* be doing continuously or often. So *I sometimes / Sometimes I don't **know what day of the week it is*** are fine, but *I sometimes don't run a marathon* is probably *never* a credible utterance, and *I don't sometimes run a marathon* would only really make sense as a "quirky" way of disagreeing with someone who just said *You sometimes run a marathon* (instead of the more natural emphatic refutation: *I **never** run a marathon*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers regarding this part: "So I sometimes / Sometimes I don't know what day of the week it is are fine",  if I used "sometimes"  at the end of the sentence( I don't know what day of the week it is sometimes" ) it would be fine too and all three sentences would have the meaning A not B. Right?  A. There are many occasions when I don't know what day of the week  it is. and B. It's common for me not to know what day of the  week it is."

Comment: I don't see any difference between A - *There are many occasions when I don't know what day of the week it is* and B - *It's common for me not to know what day of the week it is*. But you should note that it's *not* idiomatic in English to say ***I don't sometimes know** what day of the week it is* (for much the same reason that the two examples in your question text are not idiomatic). It matters exactly where you put adverbs like ***sometimes, always, often,...*** - some different positions have different meanings, and some are simply "unnatural" (or would imply *very* peculiar meanings).

Comment: (*I **don't often** know what day of the week it is* is perfectly valid, though. But it  doesn't mean the same as *I **often don't** know what day of the week it is*.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  you said "It's NOT normally idiomatic to put sometimes, occasionally before don't as in the examples in your question text. Do you mean this position "I sometimes /occasionally don't drink milk " ? In this thread I had a similar sentence but I was told it's correct. I am not arguing of course. Does it depend on personal preference?"https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317709/sometimes-in-different-positions/317725317725

Comment: @FumbleFingers, sorry but I don't understand that because you also said 
 
"It doesn't usually make sense to say I sometimes don't [verb] or Sometimes I don't [verb] unless [to verb] is something you would normally be doing continuously or often. So I sometimes / Sometimes I don't know what day of the week it is are fine."  Here you used "don't" before "sometimes".

Comment: I mean utterances like *Sometimes I don't drink milk*  and *I sometimes don't drink milk* are only "natural" in some *specific* limited context where you *normally would* drink milk (obviously no-one drinks milk *continuously*). Whereas *Sometimes I / I sometimes don't know what day it is* is *always* "natural", because people normally know what day it is *all the time*. But *I don't sometimes know what day it is* is practically *always* "weird" - in fact, I can't think of *any* context where you might say that. And *I don't sometimes drink milk* is only valid as "refutation", not "assertion".