# "Sometimes" in different positions

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

Are all three positions of sometimes common in both affirmative and negative sentences? Different native speakers share different opinions. To some the third sentence sounds wrong. Should it be avoided?

1. "Sometimes I don't drink tea.
2. "I sometimes don't drink tea.
3. "I don't drink tea sometimes."
4. "Sometimes I drink tea."
5. "I drink tea sometimes."
6. "I sometimes drink tea."

Comment: As a native speaker, I would say the third sentence should be avoided. The rest have slight differences in emphasis but overall meaning is the same. In general using "sometimes" with a negative is kind of strange, because one would expect that you don't *always* drink tea. It needs to be used in a context where it's clear what the "sometimes" is excluding.

Comment: @Esther, but what is exactly wrong with it's position in the third sentence?

Comment: (3) would only be a valid utterance if someone said that you drink tea sometimes, and you retorted "I don't drink tea _sometimes_, I drink it every day!"

Comment: You might find something useful in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317495/dont-occasionally-dont-sometimes). And [my own comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317495/dont-occasionally-dont-sometimes#comment596238_317495) speaks a little to what could be a problem with your third sentence (viz. what @KateBunting just commented, just before I did )

Comment: @tkp it's not mentioned in the books, unfortunately. But in each affirmative sentence its position is common. Right? ?

Comment: @KateBuntingIs the meaning of all positive sentences and all negative sentences the same?

Comment: Sentence 2 sounds awkward to me because you've split "I" and "don't" which isn't that common. "sometimes" in your negative sentences (1-3) implies "you *always* drink tea, but sometimes you don't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them is wrong in any formal sense, and I suspect that, with one exception, all are frequently used.

The exception is, as several have commented, #3. It is perhaps more clumsy than the others and so would be used less commonly by native speakers. One way to highlight that is to notice that in all of the others it is possible to vary the meaning by choose a different word to emphasize. So we could have:

> **Sometimes** I don't drink tea.

That could be a response to someone accusing you of drinking tea all day. But we could also have:

> Sometimes I don't **drink** tea.

Now the response may be to someone who hasn't noticed that sometimes you consume tea by simply chewing its leaves.

The same goes for the other sentences, *except* for #3. To my ear, it allows for only one emphasis:

> I don't drink tea **sometimes**.

And as per our comments, that would probably be taken as an objection to the someone claiming you are a mere amateur in your tea drinking because you drink it only **sometimes**. The tacit follow-on is "I drink it all the time!"

The point being that for most situations, you are better off using #1 and #2 (for the negative case).

But as I said, there is no formal rule governing this. On the surface, 1, 2, and even 3 are the same; as are 4, 5, and 6. Any difference is mere convention.

Comment: thank you so much! Does the emphasis change in positive sentences too?

Comment: Sure. Compare "I drink tea **sometimes**" with "I drink **tea** sometimes". The first suggests that I don't drink tea **all the time**"; but the second could suggest that **coffee** is my drink of choice from time to time.

Comment: then the emphasized *sometimes* in "sometimes I drink tea" could also imply that there are occasions when I drink tea but most of the time I drink something else. In "I sometimes drink tea" *sometimes* can imply that I don't drink it all the time. Right? If I am right then the list of possible meanings is endless, isn't it? Because in each of them I can choose to emphasize each word. Right?

Comment: Well perhaps not "endless", but certainly more meanings than one might think at first glance. Consider something as simple as "The cat sat on the mat." Read simply it means...well, simply that there was a cat on a mat. But depending on the context it could also be used to indicate that whoever sat on the chair, it wasn't the cat; or that the cat didn't sit on the floor wearing the mat as a kind of headscarf; or perhaps that the cat's position while on the mat was one of sitting, and not lolling about (as cats tend to do); and so on.

Comment: do you mean the meaning of these sentences  can also change? I mean the meaning you wrote next to them which depends on the position of "sometimes" .  "So we could have:

Sometimes I don't drink tea.

That could be a response to someone accusing you of drinking tea all day. But we could also have:

Sometimes I don't drink tea.

Now the response may be to someone who hasn't noticed that sometimes you consume tea by simply chewing its leaves."

Comment: could you tell me please how this sentence "I sometimes don't drink tea" is usually understood? We discussed the other sentences, but not this one.